# Load multiple log4j property files with log4jConfigLocation

Tags: java, log4j, web.xml

Is it possible to load multiple log4j property files with log4jConfigLocation?

I want to load log4j_prop1 and log4j_prop2 property files for log4j in my web.xml. I know it sounds weird to have multiple set of log4j property files for a single application, but still I want to know if it's possible?

What could be the possible web.xml entries?

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>

  <param-value>log4j_prop1.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>

  <param-value>log4j_prop2.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?